# awk find all matches within record, but limit to certain fields on those lines

Tags: awk

I have a record that looks like this:

```
interface Vlan5
 description customerA
 ip address 1.1.1.1 255.255.255.0
 ip address 2.2.2.1 255.255.255.0
 ip address 3.3.3.1 255.255.255.0
 no ip redirects
 no ip unreachables
 no ip proxy-arp
 standby delay reload 90
 standby 9 ip 1.1.1.1
 standby 9 ip 2.2.2.1 secondary
 standby 9 ip 3.3.3.1 secondary
 standby 9 timers 2 6
 standby 9 preempt delay minimum 60
```

I need to find all matches of "ip address" and get the 3rd and 4th fields from those lines (the IP addresses). I've got it so I'm looking at the right record, but can't figure out how to return multiple matches on fields within a given record, whose locations will vary like that. Here is the non-working code snippet, that gets me returns on "ip address" but I'm not sure how to get the two fields following that (or if that is the best approach).

```
if ... blah blah

custvlan=$(echo $i | awk 'BEGIN { FS="," } { print $4 }')

awk -v custvlan=$custvlan 'BEGIN { RS="!"; FS=" " }
{ if ( $1 ~ "interface" && $2 ~ "Vlan" )
    { seenvlan=gensub(/^Vlan/, "", "g", $2)
        if ( seenvlan == custvlan )
            match($0,/ip address/); print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
    }
}
END {
}' device-config-file
```

I also tried resetting the RS to be new-line, hoping it would work in a nested fashion but it doesn't appear so. The below modified example prints fields 3 and 4 from the first example above, not 1.1.1.1 255.255.255.0

```
if ( seenvlan == custvlan )
    RS="\n"; print "this is seenvlan " seenvlan
    if ( $1 ~ ip && $2 ~ address )
        print $3 " " $4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `split()` with newlines for the whole block, and for each line `split()` again to extract fields and do a check for the first two of them, like:

```
awk -v custvlan=$custvlan 'BEGIN { RS="!"; FS=" " }
{ if ( $1 ~ "interface" && $2 ~ "Vlan" )
    { seenvlan=gensub(/^Vlan/, "", "g", $2)
        if ( seenvlan == custvlan )
            split($0, lines, "\n")
            for (l in lines) {
                line = lines[l]
                split(line, fields, " ")
                if (fields[1] == "ip" && fields[2] == "address") {
                    print fields[3], fields[4]
                }
            }  
    }
}
END {
}' device-config-file
```

It yields:

```
1.1.1.1 255.255.255.0
2.2.2.1 255.255.255.0
3.3.3.1 255.255.255.0
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, it works great. It's also very easy to read and understand for a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without using `RS`.  For example when `custvlan` is set to `5` in bash:

```
awk -v custvlan=$custvlan '/^interface/ { show=$2=="Vlan" custvlan ? 1 : 0 }
    show && /ip address/ { print $3,$4 }' device-config-file
1.1.1.1 255.255.255.0
2.2.2.1 255.255.255.0
3.3.3.1 255.255.255.0
```

Creates a virtual "record" by setting the `show` variable on matching the `custvlan` variable and only prints out data from the `ip address` lines when `show` is set.

Comment: I actually took the leading space out of the input data originally and was puzzled when gawk still worked when I put it back.  If you see `address 1.1.1.1...` then use `$4,$5` in the print statement to align the fields.  Depends on whether or not the leading space is considered a delimiter.  With the default `FS` in GNU awk, seems like it's ignored, while setting `FS="[[:space]]"` forces the leading space to be parsed and requires the shift.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would you please expand a bit on part "{ show=$2=="Vlan" custvlan ? 1 : 0 }"? I think understand the first bit, if field2 equals Vlan, set show to be Vlan"custvlan". But what are is the "? 1 : 0" doing here?

Comment: Of course.  Think about it this way:  `show` is a "boolean" that indicates when to parse `/ip address/` lines and is set at the start of a record (`/^interface/` lines).  The variable `show` is being set to either 1 or 0 depending on if `$2` matches the concatenated string combination of `Vlan` + the value of `custvlan` (making `Vlan5` in this case) using awk's [ternary operator](http://code.wikia.com/wiki/Ternary_operator).  It would be more apparent like this: `show=($2=="Vlan" custvlan) ? 1 : 0`.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, using `RS="!"` to identify blocks (as in another answer, given above, I'm assuming a Cisco IOS configuration format), and `FS="\n"` to split each block into lines. Testing for `interface VlanX` (`custvlan` expected in command line), then looping through each line in the block in turn, and splitting those that begin with `ip address` on spaces. Field numbering and array indexing adjusted for empty fields. For efficiency, it assumes only one such block, so once found it exits.

Tested on Mac OS X 10.9 with `/usr/bin/awk`, `gawk`, and `mawk`.

```
    BEGIN {
        RS = "!"
        FS = "\n"
    }

    $2 ~ "^ *interface Vlan" custvlan {
        for (i=2; i<=NF; ++i) {
            if ($i ~ /^ *ip address /) {
                split($i, a, / */)
                print a[4], a[5]
            }
        }
        exit 0
    }
```

Sample input:

```
    !
    ! Last configuration change at 16:21:26 EEST Thu Sep 6 2012 by admin
    ! NVRAM config last updated at 16:21:46 EEST Thu Sep 6 2012 by admin
    !
    version 15.1
    service timestamps debug datetime localtime
    service timestamps log datetime localtime
    no platform punt-keepalive disable-kernel-core
    !
    !
    interface Vlan5
     description customerA
     ip address 1.1.1.1 255.255.255.0
     ip address 2.2.2.1 255.255.255.0
     ip address 3.3.3.1 255.255.255.0
     no ip redirects
     no ip unreachables
     no ip proxy-arp
     standby delay reload 90
     standby 9 ip 1.1.1.1
     standby 9 ip 2.2.2.1 secondary
     standby 9 ip 3.3.3.1 secondary
     standby 9 timers 2 6
     standby 9 preempt delay minimum 60
    !
    interface Vlan6
     description customerB
     ip address 4.4.4.4 255.255.255.0
     ip address 5.5.5.1 255.255.255.0
     ip address 6.6.6.1 255.255.255.0
     no ip redirects
     no ip unreachables
     no ip proxy-arp
     standby delay reload 90
     standby 9 ip 1.1.1.1
     standby 9 ip 2.2.2.1 secondary
     standby 9 ip 3.3.3.1 secondary
     standby 9 timers 2 6
     standby 9 preempt delay minimum 60
    !
    end
```

Usage:

```
    script.awk custvlan=5 sample.txt
    => 1.1.1.1 255.255.255.0
    => 2.2.2.1 255.255.255.0
    => 3.3.3.1 255.255.255.0

    script.awk custvlan=6 sample.txt
    => 4.4.4.4 255.255.255.0
    => 5.5.5.1 255.255.255.0
    => 6.6.6.1 255.255.255.0
```

A more robust solution (for example, safe against stray `!` characters, eg in descriptions), is the following, which requires `mawk` or `gawk`, which support regular expressions in `RS`. Usage is the same:

```
    BEGIN {
        RS = "\n( *!\n)+"
        FS = "\n"
    }

    $1 ~ "^ *interface Vlan" custvlan {
        for (i = 2; i <= NF; ++i) {
            if ($i ~ /^ *ip address /) {
                split($i, a, / */)
                print a[4], a[5]
            }
        }
        exit 0
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Another helpful answer to solving the problem.